# Sitecore internal links to media files?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

In a Sitecore 6.5 solution, i have the following;

```
<sc:Text runat="server" Field="bodyText"/>
```

and

```
Sitecore.Context.Item["bodyText"]
```

I use the latter many places in the solution - the first not so much.
I have now discovered that when using the latter, all links to the medialibrary is in the format `~/media/31F0E8084F9443789F25836A2B285D3E.ashx` even though `Media.UseItemPaths` is set to `true` in the web.config.

However, when i use the first mentioned method `<sc:Text />` the links to medialibrary items are in the correct format (without the guid, but the folder structure of the media library).

Whats going on?

Comment: Could you check what is in the source of the page - whether there is a tilda character at the beginning or %7e instead of tilda? E.g. ~/media/31F0E8084F9443789F25836A2B285D3E.ashx or %7e/media/31F0E8084F9443789F25836A2B285D3E.ashx ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As halbherz mentioned the latter

```
Sitecore.Context.Item["bodyText"]
```

is the literal value of the field. It doesn't go through the sitecore `RenderField` pipeline so none of the links get expanded.

If you want to render a field from the code behind you can use the `FieldRenderer` class like:

```
Sitecore.Web.UI.WebContols.FieldRenderer.Render("bodyText", Sitecore.Context.Item)
```

Comment: This is what I was gonna write. In Sitecore 6.X you need to use either <sc:text> or the FieldRenderer to "render" the links correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add further clarification (what @halbherz and @marto say is totally correct) just so you can better understand ~why~ they are like this.

Within RichText fields links to media and other sitecore items are stored in this format (~/media/31F0E8084F9443789F25836A2B285D3E.ashx) using the 'short GUID' of the item so that if someone renames or moves your media / content item then the link will still be valid (rather than embed the full name & path to the item in the field).

When you use the FieldRenderer (or controls that inherit from FieldRenderer such as sc:text / sc:image etc) the `RenderField` pipeline is called and the links are processed by the `LinkManager` (see your web.config `<LinkManager>` section for more info on config). The LinkManager exists so that all links are processed in a consistent manner. Calling the field value directly bypasses this pipeline and you get the raw text of the field.

You can create your own links similar to this using : `LinkManager.GetDynamicUrl(item);`

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a control which goes through certain pipelines and redners saved item references as friendly urls.

The second one is a direct value call which returns the value unedited.
To get a friednly url you should use the control.

Why do you need to call the value directly?